# Telerik RadCaptcha / How Can We Validate RadCaptcha From Code Behind / WithOut Using Validation Group

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, captcha

How Can We Check The Validation Of RadCaptcha From Code Behind  - With Custom Validator(ServerValidate) / WithOut Using And Setting ValidationGroup ?

thanks In Future Advance

Best Regards...

Comment: i would be apprecite for helping me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether the correct code was entered by using the RadCaptcha's IsValid property. To be sure that validation has occurred please invoke the RadCaptcha's and Page's Validate method:

```
RadCaptcha1.Validate();
Page.Validate();

if(RadCaptcha1.IsValid)
{
     //TODO: Add your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you will have to find a way to associate your custom validator with the textbox rendered by the captcha. You should be able to access it via the ValidatedTextBox property of RadCaptcha.

Comment: hi / thanks 4 ur answer / i set an id 4 validated text box of captcha and i am not using default text box of captcha...